# Accessing viewdata object in view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have been getting into MVC ASP.NET, the potential is very exciting. I have become slightly stuck on a bit and wondered if anyone could give advice, please.

I have worked out how to bundle type object into the viewdata and then access them in a view.

In the view I pick up my viewdata object and assign it to corresponding type.

```
    @using MyPro.Models;
    @{
      var viewDataMyObj = ViewData["MyObj"] as MyObj;
    }
```

I then pick it up further down and successfully access my {get,set} and populate a DropDownListFor...

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => viewDataMyObj.myVar, new      SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)viewDataMyObj.mySel.OrderBy(c => c.Value), "Value", "Text", "Select All"), new { @Class = "form-control" })
```

So, mySel is in my Model and works. It's the string myVar, I can't assign it as an id field. It literally takes "viewDataMyObj.myVar" and puts it as an ID, not the contents of myVar which is "hello". I'm definitely lacking a bit of knowledge at this and would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.DropDownListFor` is supposed to work with your Model only. Applying it to `viewDataMyObj.myVar` won't work.
From the code shown, there is no evidence that your view has a model (don't confuse `using` with `model`)
Assuming that your view supposed to work with `MyObj` model and that `MyObj` has `myVar` property, which is supposed to be filled from drop down this should work:

```
@model MyPro.Models.MyObj
@{
    var viewDataMyObj = ViewData["MyObj"] as MyObj;
 }

 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.myVar, new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)viewDataMyObj.mySel.OrderBy(c => c.Value), "Value", "Text", "Select All"), new { @Class = "form-control" })
```

You can see that `DropDownListFor` is for `x.myVar` which is the property of your model and not for `viewDataMyObj.myVar`

In addition, if your model is MyObj and it also contains the data to fill your dropdown, you don't need to use ViewData at all:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.myVar, 
    Model.mySel.OrderBy(c => c.Value)
      .Select(c => new SelectListItem{Value = c.Value, Text = c.Text}),     
   "Select All", 
   new { @Class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: You can not use multiple models in the same view. From your comment I assume that you don't understand how MVC works and I suggesst to read about MVC concept in general and about ASP.NET MVC in particular. And one important thing: EVERYTHING THAT CAN BE DONE WITH WEB FORMS COULD BE DONE WITH MVC. MVC is a pattern that allows you to structure your code so it could be more maintainable

Comment: Those are not models!!!!. those are just classes. View can have only one model. You need to specify it in view like this `@model  Namespace.Models.Modelname2`

Answer (score 0):

Try `myVar.Value` when creating the ID

Worked for me...